# Uploading a csv file to sql server - Identity problem

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, csv, sqlbulkcopy

Given a column structure in a CSV file of:

```
First_Name, Last_Name, Date_Of_Birth
```

And a SQL Server table with a structure of

```
ID(PK) | First_Name | Last_Name | Date_Of_Birth
```

(Field ID is an Identity with an auto-increment of 1)

How do i arrange it so that SQL Server does not attempt to insert the First_Name column from the csv file into the ID field?

For info the csv is loaded into a DataTable and then copied to SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy

Should i be modifying the csv file before the import  add the ID column (The destination table is truncated prior to import, so no need to worry about duplicate key values.) Or perhaps adding an id column to the Datatable?

Or Is there a setting in Sql Server that i may have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the ID column to the datatable, but do not worry about populating that field with data from the CSV.

Once that is done the data should line up fine and since ID is a Identity with Auto-Increment you should be fine with loading the CSV into the DB.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else stumbling along this problem use DataTable.Columns.Add("ID").SetOrdinal(0) to add the ID column to the beginning of the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping.aspx

Comment: That only works if the column is actually in the CSV file already doesn't it?

Comment: You should add a mapping for First_Name, Last_Name, Date_Of_Birth.
ID will be auto generated because it is an ID column.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going with Tony's solution as some there are a lot of CSV files with lots of columns. Adding column mappings for all of them will take ages!